# How to make changes in JSON property names while parsing

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

According to [JSON.parse documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), there is a reviver function that can be passed to make changes in the value of each property in the JSON data.
for example

```
JSON.parse('{"FirstNum": 1, "SecondNum": 2, "ThirdNum": 3}', function(k, v) {
  return v * 2;
});
```

How could I make changes in property names? like changing from *pascal case* to *came case*?

Comment: while parsing you can't. You can do it after parsing is done and object is created

Comment: @gurvinder372, yes we can)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to achieve this is to create another object and then `map` the first one.

```js
var jsonObject = JSON.parse('{"FirstNum": 1, "SecondNum": 2, "ThirdNum": 3}');
var newObject = {};
Object.keys(jsonObject).map(function(key) {
  var newKey = key[0].toLowerCase() + key.substr(1);
  newObject[newKey] = jsonObject[key];
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(newObject)); // ugly display of result
```

Comment: I've checked your approach and [humps](https://github.com/domchristie/humps/blob/master/humps.js)'s in Jsperf, but the performance ratio is both of them was 5% comparing to only parsing the JSON without corrections. which is a considerable drop and is not suitable for mobile devices. Although seems there no better way

Comment: If you focus on performance at frontend then why not making a conversion at backend?

Comment: You're right. That's a better approach .I just tried not to pass the task to other guys. Thank you